# Installed grub on flashdrive

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, tar

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 on my flash and then deleted windows as I ran Ubuntu on my USB drive. I found out after research I downloaded the grub on my USB drive. I tried basic commands to fix it and this is my current results

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
```

please help! I need to know how to do this because I am trying to boot Ubuntu without the use of my USB. I tried downloading *unetbootin*. My results are:

> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> unetbootin : Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
> Recommends: extlinux but it is not installable
> Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: ...and what's the problem with grub being on my usb drive? What exactly do you want to acheive?

Comment: i want to be able start my computer without the usb and be able to acess ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try boot-repair

"Boot-Repair" is a small graphical tool to repair frequent boot problems.
To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Source:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769482

Comment: unfortually it still didnt install

Comment: i think if i could just get unetbootin to run it might be able to install it on the hard disk so i can run ubuntu without the use of my flash drive but my results are:

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unetbootin : Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not installable
   Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Have you tried to fix broken packages with "sudo apt-get install -f" ?